# Html5 video tag not working in chrome

Tags: html

On a W3school video tag tutorial, I checked on Chrome and it was working fine but I copied the code in my project and it didn't work. Here is the code:

```
<video width="500" height="400" controls autoplay>
    <source src="C:\Users\Sunny\Desktop\My_Passion.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>              
</video>
```

Answer (score 1):

The video source URL has to point to your web server where this page is being hosted. It won't work for local file paths like the one you currently have in there (pointing to a video file on your local computer).

So make sure the My_Passion.mp4 file is on your web server and then change the source as follows:

```
<source src="My_Passion.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
```

Comment: what if i want to show the video on localhost whether it will work or not.?

Comment: i am using codeigniter
         <video width="500" height="400" controls>
    <source src="<?php base_url()    ?>video\My_Passion.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    
    </video>

Comment: It will work on localhost if the file is in the same directory as your HTML/PHP file is.

Comment: Make sure you use forward slashes to set the path: 
`src="<?php base_url() ?>/video/My_Passion.mp4"`

Comment: yes i use forward slahes to set the path like  <source src="<?php echo base_url() ?>/video/My_Passion.mp4" type="video/mp4">

Comment: i tried it on IE it didn't show me the video but due to the extension of idm it download the video.

Comment: So what is the URL generated on the page? (if you use View Source in the browser). Does it download the video if you open that URL directly in the browser?

Comment: it generates that url http://localhost/hospital/video/My_Passion.mp4
if i open it on IE it download the video but in chrome it show the page in this it use the default player but didn't display the video but in firefox it play the video if i simply paste the link

Comment: Did you try using Chrome's Developer Tools to see if it tries to download and play the video? (have a look in the Network tab when you refresh the page)

Answer (score 0):

Chrome does not support .mp4 video codec. ReEncode video.

`<video width="500" height="400" controls autoplay>
    <source src="C:\Users\Sunny\Desktop\My_Passion.mp4" type="video/mp4"/> 
    <source src="C:\Users\Sunny\Desktop\My_Passion.ogv" type="video/ogg"/>

</video>`

You can use [online video converter](http://video.online-convert.com/convert-to-ogg)

Comment: I see conflicting documentation about Chrome support mp4 codec, it plays my mp4 video and I am using Chrome version 46.0.2490.80